# Proof about vertices of a convex hull

Tags: convex-analysis

how to prove that, given a set defined as

$S_{k}$ = {y: y = Ax, $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq$ 1}

its convex hull conv($S_{k}$) has its vertices defined by those vectors $x$ such that $\|x\|_{\infty}$ = 1. How to do it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Except I'm missing something in your statements, the claim is false (is there a miswrite somewhere ?). Take for example $A = 2I$. Then $S$ can't have a vertex with $\|x\|_\infty = 1$. BTW, note that $\mathrm{conv}(S) = S$ because $S$ is convex, being the linear image of a convex set.

Comment: @dohmatob, why isn't $y=2x$ for any $\|x\|_\infty=1$ a vertex in that case?

Comment: Oops! I commented @MichaelGrant comment but, i can't see it (my response) here anymore. Anyways, ok, yes I misread buzz's problem. MichaelGrant's comment / question, clarified what i was missing in the original question. Thanks to both of you, and ignore my first remark.

Comment: @buzz: I propose you reformulate your problem to precisely reflect the fact that your claim is that $vertices(\{Ax| \|x\|_\infty \le 1\}) \subseteq \{Ax | \|x\|_\infty = 1\}$. There is nothing more confusing than an imprecisely stated problem :)

Comment: @dohmatob: yes, I agree with you. In fact in this post I've not been precise, but I will in my dissertation :) thank you for your help

Comment: OK, in that case, check my answer below, wherein we show that $vertices(\{Ax| \|x\|_\infty \le 1\}) \subseteq \{Ax | \|x\|_\infty = 1\}$ indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the set under study is a linear image $S := A\mathbb{B}_\infty$, of $\mathbb{B}_\infty := \{x | \|x\|_\infty \le 1\}$, the  unit ball for the $\ell_\infty$-norm . We're interested in the vertices of $S$, namely $V(S)$. Define
\begin{equation}V_0 := \{Ax | \|x\|_\infty = 1\}.
\end{equation}
The aim is to show that $V(S) \subseteq V_0$.

Suppose on the contrary that $S$ has a vertex $ v = Ax$, with $\|x\|_\infty < 1$. We'll produce a contradiction. Now, by definition of $v$ as a vertex of $S$, there exists a half-space $H^+ := \{y|\langle w, y\rangle \le \lambda\}$ which contains $S$ and such that the intersection of its boundary $\partial H^+ = \{y | \langle w, y\rangle = \lambda\}$ with $S$ is the singleton $\{v\}$. Now, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{equation}
Ax \in \partial H^+ \land \|x\|_\infty < 1 \implies \lambda = \langle w, Ax\rangle = \langle A^*w, x\rangle \le \|A^*w\|_1\|x\|_\infty < \|A^*w\|_1.
\end{equation}
Finally, invoking the above inequality, the compacity of $\mathbb{B}_\infty$, and using the fact that $H^+ \supseteq S$, one has $\langle w, Az\rangle \le \lambda < \|A^*w\|_1 $ for all $z \in \mathbb{B}_\infty$, and so $\max_{z \in \mathbb{B}_\infty} \langle A^*w, z\rangle < \|A^*w\|_1$, i.e $\|A^*w\|_1 < \|A^*w\|_1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) just one question: doesn't your proof prove that V(S) and $V_{0}$ coincide (which is our aim)?  In fact you show that there is no possibility to have a vertex with $\|x\|_{\infty}$ < 1

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't in itself prove that "once we have $\|x\|_\infty = 1$ then $Ax$ must be a vertex of $S$". The other direction of the inclusion is a whole different business :). Please consider rewriting your (original) question as precisely and formally as you can, including all the details.

Comment: I think that your proof is what I was searching for. Just one thing: it is not given for granted that all vectors $x$ with $\|x\|_{\infty}$ = 1 will define a vertex of S, but no $x$ such that $\|x\|_{\infty}$ < 1 can. Again, thank you!

Comment: Yes, you get it: the last part of the 2nd sentence in your statement is precisely what has been proved, but nothing more :).

Comment: which was also the most challenging part for me :)